# Unchecked Checkboxes in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, checkbox

Hi all I have a few checkboxes in Codeigniter, eg:

```
$data = array(
    'name'        => 'newsletter',
    'id'          => 'newsletter',
    'value'       => 'accept',
    'checked'     => TRUE,
    'style'       => 'margin:10px',
    );

echo form_checkbox($data);
```

eg produces:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="accept" checked="checked" style="margin:10px" />
```

is there a way that I can check in codeigniter whether the box has been selected or not in my controller? if I use $this->input->post('newsletter') and the box has been selected will the value be false? if so how can I run form validation on the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$data = $this->input->post('newsletter') gives you the value of the checkbox that was selected.

You may also go through the following links:

1. [Get checkbox values in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112863/how-to-get-checkbox-values-using-php-code-ignitor-in-controller).
2. [Checking checkbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997782/codeigniter-checking-checkbox-value)

Answer (score 0):

the checkbox value is empty when this component is unchecked, you want see the data use:

```
print_r($_POST)
```

you can see all the string passed in the post method